# NSPopover doesn't receive first click after opening

Tags: swift, macos, mouseevent, popover, nspopover

I have an NSPopover which I have set the `contentViewController` of and am using to display some custom UI. The popover is set to toggle open when the user clicks the status item in the status bar at the top of their mac. The issue I'm currently facing is that when I open the popover it always takes one click anywhere on the window before the buttons on the popover will start responding to clicks. The way my buttons are implemented is that they are NSView subclasses in which I have overridden the methods like `override func mouseDown (with event: NSEvent)`. This is the code I use to open the popover:

```
guard let button = statusItem.button else { return }
popoverView.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
```

Does anyone know what I can do to ensure that the popover window becomes immediately responsive to mouse events upon being opened?

Comment: did you try `window.makeKey()`

Comment: That did it! Thanks @LeoDabus

Comment: My app only has popover, so how do I get window ?

Answer (score 1):

If your app only has popover menu, then you need to get the `NSWindow` from that popover.

```
@objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
            if self.popover.isShown {
                self.popover.performClose(sender)
            } else {
                self.popover.show(
                    relativeTo: button.bounds,
                    of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY
                )
                self.popover
                    .contentViewController?
                    .view.window?
                    .makeKey()
            }
        }
    }
```

If you already have the instance of the `NSWindow`, it should as simple as call the `window.makeKey()`, like in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484765/nspopover-doesnt-receive-first-click-after-opening#comment97679211_55484765)